# Prisma - How to Make Variable Product Schema?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I want to make variable product schema in prisma, like woocommerce variable product.

[this is my model, how can i make it for simple and variable product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsdqA.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to add attributes to the `product` model.

For simple attributes like size, you could use [enums](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#enum):

```
enum Size {
  S
  M
}

model Product {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  sizes Size[]
}
```

If you want to carry additional info with your attributes, you should create new [model and relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations):

```
model Size {
  id        String    @id @default(cuid())
  name      String
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  products  Product[]
}

model Product {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  sizes Size[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want schema with variations price not just attributes.